# How to set a new numeric index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have read data from a json file, and the dataframe looks like:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
A:   1    Hi    7
B:   22   CC    1
```

I think it is because the file was a dictionary of dictionaries and I do not need the outer dictionary key, which is now showing as index identifier (A and B)

I need to change A and B to normal index numbers, such as 0 and 1. I tried the following:

```
myDf = myDf.reset_index()
```

It worked, but I see an additional column named index which has values A and B. I tried dropping this,

```
 myDf.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

but now I see another column named level_0.

Could you point out what is the right approach to this? Thanks

Comment: myDf.reset_index(inplace=True) If you want to drop also the old index myDf.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Would you like to add it as an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: yes, thank you. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be :

```
myDf.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

If you want to drop also the old index

```
myDf.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```